# Minimum & Maximum - having two compulsory conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 columns with the following name: 
**name1**, **name2** and **value**.
I want to obtain in another sheet two tables having two compulsory condition (min and max calculated using **name1** and **name2**):

the name of the first table to be taken from the column with **name2** and this table has two partition. 
the first partition named max, is calculating the max for `30_-20, 40_-20, 50_-20, 30_22, 40_22, 50_22, 30_60, 40_60, 50_60` and second partition named min, is calculating the min for `30_-20, 40_-20, 50_-20, 30_22, 40_22, 50_22, 30_60, 40_60, 50_60`. 
What I want to say can be viewed in the following picture.

[image]

I need this for my job, and I don't know anything about macros. I think it will be necessary to learn macros.

Comment: See [MINIF, MAXIF and MODEIF with Array Formulas](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/wiki/office_2013_release-excel/minif-maxif-and-modeif-with-array-formulas/e81c39b9-458e-46cb-b8cf-12ffbc20794c) and [MINIF, MAXIF and MODEIF with Standard Formulas](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/wiki/office_2013_release-excel/minif-maxif-and-modeif-with-standard-formulas/144a2f30-31ef-408e-86c3-f1443d9ac1fd).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a layout on a single worksheet similar to your sample image.

[image: MAXIF and MINIF two conditions criteria]

The standard formula(s) for G3, I3, M3 and O3 are:

```
=MAX(INDEX($C$2:$C$999*($A$2:$A$999=H3)*($B$2:$B$999=H$1), , ))
=MIN(INDEX($C$2:$C$999+(($A$2:$A$999<>H3)+($B$2:$B$999<>H$1))*1E+99, , ))
=MAX(INDEX($C$2:$C$999*($A$2:$A$999=N3)*($B$2:$B$999=N$1), , ))
=MIN(INDEX($C$2:$C$999+(($A$2:$A$999<>N3)+($B$2:$B$999<>N$1))*1E+99, , ))
```

Fill down as necessary. It is usually easier to reference a cell containing a value (e.g. *30_-20*) than repeatedly hardcoding the value into a variety of similar formulas. I've used H3:H5 and N3:N5 for the column A values.

**How it Works:**

See [MINIF, MAXIF and MODEIF with Standard Formulas](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/wiki/office_2013_release-excel/minif-maxif-and-modeif-with-standard-formulas/144a2f30-31ef-408e-86c3-f1443d9ac1fd).

Comment: Thanks. One more question, please.
It is obviously that these formula help me to answer to my question, but in calculation of MIN it is not very clearly for me.

you put <>H3. Why? I should have put =H3, not <>H3. 
What does 1E+99 mean? 
can you explain these, please?
Thanks

Comment: I put a lot of effort into explaining how these formulas work at the links provided in my comment to your original question. If there is something there that you do not understand, please feel free to come back and ask a specific question and I will try to address it.